# In the following problems the universe is R. Determine the following

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

In the following problems the universe is R. Determine the following.

a)[0,3] ∪ [2,6]

b)[0,3] - [2,6]

c)[0,3] ⊕ [2,6]

So I just need someone to confirm if I am correct or not in my solution..
I have

**a) {0,2,3,6}**

**b) {0,3}**

but I am not sure what to do for **c)**. According to the book $\oplus$ means symmetric difference.

Thanks for your time

Comment: $R$ are the real numbers?

Comment: It probably means: $A\oplus B:= \{x: x=a+b, \ a\in A, \ b\in B\}$.

Comment: @AaronMaroja I'm not really sure unfortunately.

Comment: @AlexR. So what exactly does that mean? a is an element of A b is a element of B so what I do 0+2 and 3+6 to get {2,9} ?

Comment: For a), the union or the two intervals should be $[0,6]$ (if this helps, draw a line to get an idea). In particular, the union is at least as big as $[0,3]$, which has uncountably many elements: the union cannot be $\{0,2,3,6\}$, which has only 4. Similarly, drawing the real line helps for b): the answer is $[0,2)$ (all elements of $[0,3]$ that are not in $[2,6]$).

Comment: From you answers, it seems that you interpret $[0,3]$ as a set, but $[0,3]$ is usually the notation for a closed interval. Which is it?

Comment: @user3325915: Yes, it's every possible $x$ you can make by summing pairs of elements from the two sets. On the other hand, Clement C.'s question is much more pressing.

Comment: @mrp You are correct, I am interpreting it incorrectly. It is not a set.

Comment: so would c) be [2,9]

Comment: Hmm, my immediate understanding of $\oplus$ in this context would be the symmetric difference of the sets. Impossible to really tell without knowing the conventions of the book/course the problem is from.

Comment: @HenningMakholm problem is from Discrete Mathematics. It looks like it implies The statement A ⊕ B is true when either A or B, but not both, are true.

Comment: @user3325915: Unfortunately the _name_ of the course doesn't tell much about which conventions are used in that particular course at that particular institution.

Comment: @HenningMakholm just found it in my book. It's the symmetric difference of A and B

Comment: @user3325915: Good. I've edited that into the question. "Symmetric difference" is indeed the set-equivalent of "exclusive or".

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ahh, now how do I get a solution for C? would **[2,9]** be correct?

Comment: @user3325915: No, not by far. Do you really think $[2,9]$ is the set of all numbers that are in either $[0,3]$ or $[2,6]$ but not in both??

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm just taking a guess. would it be [1,2] or [3,4,5] ?

Comment: @user3325915: I've just figured out what your misunderstanding is. See my just-posted answer. (Note that the notation $[3,4,5]$ is not meaningful).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're misunderstanding the notation in the problem. Your answers to (a) and (b) would be entirely correct if the problem said $\{0,3\}$ and $\{2,6\}$, but what is actually there is $[0,3]$ and $[2,6]$ -- which is notation for *intervals* of the real line.

$[0,3]$ is by definition a shorthand notation for the set $\{x\mid 0\le x\le 3\}$ of all numbers that are between $0$ and $3$, including these endpoints.

Similarly $[2,6]$ is the set of numbers between (and including) $2$ and $6$.

With this knowledge I think you should be able to find correct answers yourself.

Comment: [3,4] Is what I'm thinking..

Comment: @user3325915: That can't be the answer to any of the questions, because $4$ isn't an endpoint of any of the two given intervals. So, for example, the numbers $3.999$ and $4.001$ are both in $[2,6]$ and both _not_ in $[0,3]$. Therefore, no matter which set operation you perform on $[0,3]$ and $[2,6]$, the numbers $3.999$ and $4.001$ will either both be in the result or neither of them will be. So the result of such an operation can't possibly be $[3,4]$ which contains $3.999$ but not $4.001$.

Comment: hmmmmm... [2,3], and if that's not correct I have no clue.

Comment: @user3325915: $[2,3]$ is $[0,3]\cap[2,6]$. But that is not one of the questions. (And it's not clear to me _which_ of the questions you're guessing for a solution of).

Comment: I'm trying to figure out c) ....

Comment: @user3325915: Then you want the set of all numbers that are _either_ between 0 and 3, _or_ between 2 and 6 but are not both between 0 and 3 and between 2 and 6. Which numbers are that?

Comment: @user3325915: Note that you also need to correct your answers to (a) and (b).

Comment: Idk. [0,1] is between 0 and 3 but not between 2 and 6.

Comment: @user3325915: $[0,1]$ are certainly _some_ of the numbers with the desired property, but how about, for example, $1.5$ or $5.22$ or $6$? The question asks for the set of _all_ numbers that are in exactly one of the two intervals.